# remove duplicate headers in hive-beeline

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, pyspark, beeline

```
Select ACCOUNT_NUMBER, BIN AS RISK_BIN FROM test.daily_call_routing2;" 
| python -c 'exec("import sys;import csv;reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin, 
dialect=csv.excel_tab);writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, 
dialect=csv.excel)\nfor row in reader: writer.writerow(row)")' > 
$EXPORT_DIR//home/rabbid160/test_$DATE_STR.csv;**
```

When I'm trying to execute the above command in beeline-hive, I am able to see the data however with multiple headers in between. Can anyone please tell me how this can be solved to only one header and data following.

```
Example as follows:
```

+-------------------+-----------+--+
|  account_number   | risk_bin  |
+-------------------+-----------+--+
| 8498310230444304  | 2         |
| 8778104140754717  | 2         |
| 8155100513664825  | 2         |
| 8155100513664825  | 2         |
| 8155400040004812  | 2         |
| 8155200521190266  | 2         |
| 8155300210482543  | 2         |
| 8497202241094288  | 2         |
| 8155500010197049  | 2         |
+-------------------+-----------+--+
|  account_number   | risk_bin  |
+-------------------+-----------+--+
| 8155100030718781  | 2         |
| 8495444731138751  | 2         |
| 8498320015120250  | 2         |
| 8498330360083177  | 2         |
| 8155300210487112  | 2         |
| 8777701821146336  | 2         |
| 8497202461586765  | 2         |
| 8155400310837610  | 2         |

Answer (score 1):

In beeline, the number of rows after which header should be repeated is defined by beeline variable `headerinterval` .

You may set `headerinterval` using beeline command `!set headerinterval 100`

Set headerinterval to large value so that possibly you will see header only once.